# Create 2D array of integers that will fill in the matrix with random numbers using two functions. What have I done wrong?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Here is the code. I need to have fixed rows and cols that get filled in with random numbers when the matrix function is called. There needs to be 2 functions, one for displaying and 1 for randomizing.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

const int ROWS = 10;
const int COLS = 8;
int matrix[ROWS][COLS];

void RandMatrix(int **arr, int row) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            *((*arr + i) + j) = rand() % 10;
}

void DisplayMatrix(int **arr, int row) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; ++j)
            cout << matrix[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int matrix[ROWS][COLS];
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; ++j) {
            matrix[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }
    int *ptr[ROWS];
    int **arr = &ptr[0];
    int row = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        ptr[i] = &matrix[i][0];
    }
    RandMatrix(arr, row);
    DisplayMatrix(arr, row);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `*((*arr+i)+j)` to address the matrix? What is your intention with that?

Comment: You can make your life easier by using `struct Matrix { int matrix[ROWS][COLS] };` and simply declare and pass `Matrix` by reference to those functions.  That removes all of the pointer shenanigans.

Comment: your usage of pointer is wrong.  here, it's better to use your global matrix variable instead of pointers

Answer (score 2):

#### Main problem

The pointer arithmetic is wrong in the line

```
*((*arr + i) + j) = rand() % 10;
```

It needs to be

```
*(*(arr + i) + j) = rand() % 10;
```

It will be easier to just use:

```
arr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
```

#### Minor problems

1. You are passing `arr` as argument to `DisplayMatrix` but you are not using it. Instead, you are using `matrix`. It works ok by lucky coincidence. It will be better to not use `arr` in the function.
2. You are passing `row` as argument to `DisplayMatrix` but you are using `ROWS` in the `for` loop. Once again, it works because of lucky coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

You pass `arr` to `DisplayMatrix` - but you don't actually use it there. Instead, the function prints the values in the global variable named `matrix`. But those values were never initalized - `RandMatrix` populates a different variable named `matrix`, the one local to `main`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `DisplayMatrix` function with `arr` as an argument but you are not using `arr` in it at all. Instead, you are using `matrix`.

In the `DisplayMatrix` function, change the following line:

```
cout << matrix[i][j];
```

to

```
cout << *((*arr + i) + j);
```

And it will work as intended.